# Azure Devops pipelines vs Release Pipelines

Tags: c#, xamarin, azure-pipelines

We have a repository with two `C#` solutions (Xamarin and WPF). Each solution also have multiple executable projects.

At the moment we have multiple pipelines for each project. But I thin  it's better to do only one pipeline because builds will be faster because all projects have similar dependant projects and also I have to do only one checkout from repo.

I'm thinking in build all binaries and in Release pipelines create installers with `Advanced Installer`. By this way I can split build and installer creation. Is this a good approach?

Why Release pipelines still in classic mode? Whats the key difference between linked stages and parallel stages (diagram).

Also I don't understand the key difference between `PublishBuildArtifact@1` and `PublishPipelineArtifact@1` tasks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> By this way I can split build and installer creation. Is this a good approach?

Yes. This is a good approach.

From your previous description, you will use one Pipeline to build all projects.

In this case, the generated artifacts will contain many projects. If it is split into Build and Release Pipeline, installers can be created for individual project according to requirements. Without having to run the build pipeline multiple times. This will greatly improve efficiency.

> Why Release pipelines still in classic mode? Whats the key difference between linked stages and parallel stages (diagram).

For the Release Pipelines tab, it only supports classic mode for the time being. But you can also use YAML Pipeline to achieve Release feature.

It can also achieve the same function as Release Pipeline.

For the linked stages and parallel stages, linked stages will be run one by one in the order set. This method is generally used when there are dependencies between stages. Parallel stages will execute multiple stages at the same time during operation. It can shorten the pipeline running time but requires additional parallel tasks.

> I don't understand the key difference between and tasks.PublishBuildArtifact@1PublishPipelineArtifact@1

You can refer to this Github ticket: [What is the difference between build and pipeline artifacts?](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-devops-docs/issues/2341)

> Build Artifacts (published via the Publish Build Artifacts task) have been in Azure DevOps for a long time and are the built-in artifact storage mechanism for Azure Pipelines. Most builds that store non-package artifacts today would likely use this task. The task can push the content up to the server/cloud but can also copy the files to a local file share.

> Pipeline Artifacts (published using the Publish Pipeline Artifact task are intended as the replacement for Build Artifacts. The benefit of Pipeline Artifacts is that they can dramatically reduce the time it takes to upload and download large artifacts. We do this be first checking whether the content that is being uploaded exists in the service. We do this not just at the per-file level but also at the sub-file level (in up to 128K chunks). It can lead to really dramatic performance improvements.

Comment: I have seen that it's possible to have a pipeline triggered from another pipeline like a release pipeline, but it's not working for me.
resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: 'appboxCi' 
    source: '\AppBox\AppBox-CI'
    trigger: true

Configuring the trigger failed

Comment: @JuanDYB Sure. The Pipeline can trigger another pipeline. If you need to use build and release Pipeline, you need to use build artifacts in Release Pipeline.  Refer to this doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/triggers?view=azure-devops

Comment: @JuanDYB It seems that you are using Pipeline resource trigger in yaml, right?

Comment: I have edited my comment to show my yml. What I'm trying to do is one pipeline to build dlls and another pipeline dedicated to generate installers using Advanced Instaler. I ccan achieve this using release pipelines but I have seen that it's possible to do this by yml pipeline also configuring trigger pipeline. I'm not sure if it's better using yml pipelines or release pipelines or if release pipelines will be deprecated in the future

Comment: @JuanDYB There is currently no information about the release pipeline being deprecated, you can keep using it.  On the other hand, due to the limited yaml information provided, the exact cause may not be found. I suggest you create a new post and share the full YAML file. It will be helpful to check the issue.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have published the new post for that

Comment: @JuanDYB I have noticed the new ticket. I will check it when I free later.  If the answer can give you some help about the current ticket, you may consider accepting it. Thanks